# Running a project in a virtual directory of another for debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a solution containing multiple projects, 2 of these projects are a web applications, for the purposes of making it easier when debugging/navigating through each of the websites, I want to run both projects on the same port, and have one of the projects running in a virtual directory (as it does on live).

Is it possible to do this through VS?

Comment: You can configure the project to use IIS instead of IIS-Express. This would make your debug target (aspx files, dlls, configs) all live under an IIS folder

Comment: Okay cool, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the response in the comment above, changing the project to use IIS as opposed to IIS-Express worked a treat.